# «Adónde» vs «Adonde»

Tags: pronombres, ortografía, palabras-interrogativas

> Empezar con un fin en mente significa comenzar con una clara comprensión de su destino. **Significa saber adónde se está yendo, de modo que se pueda comprender mejor dónde se está**, y dar siempre los pasos adecuados en la dirección correcta.

En la cita anterior veo las palabras «adónde» y «dónde» donde yo esperaría a ver «adonde» y «donde», porque no es interrogativa.

RAE menciona [dos contextos] en que «adónde» (con acento) se aplica:

> #### donde.
>
> adv. interrog. A qué lugar.
>   ORTOGR. Escr. con acento. *¿Adónde vas?*
>
> #### de adónde.
>
> 1. loc. adv. Arg., Bol., Hond., Nic. y Ur. U. para indicar la imposibilidad de que se haga o se logre algo. *Pero de adónde alcanzarlo. Dicen que aumentarán los sueldos, ¡de adónde!*

Y [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ad%C3%B3nde#Spanish) menciona sólo el contexto interrogativo:

> (interrogative) to where
>   *¿**Adónde** vas?*
>   **Where** are you going?

O en [español](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/ad%C3%B3nde):

> Indaga acerca del movimiento o dirección de la acción.

¿Los usos de «adónde» y «dónde» arriba son correctos, o es un error ortográfico?  Si es correcto, ¿por qué?

Answer (score 7):

*"Dónde"* y *"A dónde"* van acentuados cuando son adverbios interrogativos o exclamativos (de lugar).

> [Dónde](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=nUJs7Er0gD6xFrVi7E) habré dejado las llaves? / Me pregunto dónde habré dejado las llaves.
>
> Adónde irá con tanta prisa? / Me pregunto adónde irá con tanta prisa.

No llevan el acento cuando son adverbios relativos que introducen frases subordinadas

> Las llaves estarán [donde](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=qMMxvDB32D697zToZQ) menos esperes encontrarlas. Fuimos al sitio donde estuviste ayer con Luis
>
> Hemos ido hoy adonde estuviste ayer con Luis

La RAE también dice que no es correcto preceder ["adónde" de una preposición](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=wFbvYdpRYD6ESQMlOO) (ni tampoco [*adonde*](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=58u9nK1BDD6UJ1Q6SR) sin acento). El ejemplo de ["de adónde"](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=nzaA4324eDXX2jPwc1Mn) es una [locución adverbial](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locuci%C3%B3n_adverbial) (preposición + sustantivo/adjetivo/**adverbio** cuyo significado trasciende la suma de los componentes) que se da en algunos países de america latina y como tal, aunque va en contra de esa regla de no preceder *adónde* de preposición, está aceptada.

Así que los usos que propones en la pregunta son correctos. El problema es que Wiktionary parece no estar dando la imagen completa y la RAE parece tener más de una entrada para cada uno de esos adverbios (con o sin acentos) lo que puede añadir un poco de confusión. Espero que estas otras entradas ayuden a clarificar las diferencias entre los adverbios con o sin acento:

- [Dónde](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=nUJs7Er0gD6xFrVi7E)
- [Donde](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=qMMxvDB32D697zToZQ)
- [Adónde](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=wFbvYdpRYD6ESQMlOO)
- [Adonde](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=58u9nK1BDD6UJ1Q6SR)

"Adónde" y "adonde" tienen un significado ligeramente distinto entre ellos. El primero significa "a qué lugar" y el segundo tiene un significado un poco más amplio que expresa la dirección de un movimiento. "Dónde" y "donde" tienen prácticamente el mismo significado (indicar lugar), salvo que el primero es usado para preguntas y el segundo no (indica también lugar, pero introduciendo una frase subordinada).

Answer (score 3):

El pronombre **dónde** no sólo se acentúa cuando es interrogativo. Hay otro caso especial que se da cuando es pronombre relativo.

La siguiente es una cita de [la sección de consultas lingüísticas de la RAE](http://www.rae.es/consultas/tilde-en-que-cuales-quienes-como-cuan-cuantoaosas-cuando-donde-y-adonde). Es un poco extensa pero bien aclaratoria:

> Aunque los relativos, presenten o no antecedente expreso, son normalmente átonos y se escriben sin tilde, hay casos en que pueden pronunciarse tanto con acento prosódico como sin él. Esta doble posibilidad se da cuando los relativos introducen subordinadas relativas sin antecedente expreso, siempre que el antecedente implícito sea indefinido y tenga carácter inespecífico (una persona, alguien, algo, algún lugar, nadie, nada, etc.). Esto ocurre cuando la oración de relativo sin antecedente depende de verbos como haber, tener, buscar, encontrar, necesitar, etc., que admiten complementos indefinidos de carácter inespecífico. En estos casos es aceptable escribir el relativo tanto con tilde, reflejando la pronunciación tónica, como sin ella, representando la pronunciación átona.
>
> El problema es que no hay con **qué/que** alimentar a tanta gente.
>
> Ya ha encontrado **quién/quien** le quiera y no necesita nada más.
>
> Buscó **dónde/donde** sentarse, pero no había asientos libres.
>
> No tenía **cómo/como** defenderse de las acusaciones.

En tu ejemplo hay dos casos de subordinadas con antecedente implícito indefinido e inespecífico:

> ...saber **[el lugar]** adónde se está yendo
>
> ... comprender **[el lugar]** dónde se está

En estos casos el pronombre relativo donde-adonde es tónico (se carga la voz), y puede o no llevar acento gráfico.